# How can I change the value of the variable continuously in the class(which I create)

Tags: android, multithreading, class, variables

I'm a beginner in Android.

I'm trying to make an application that performs some engineering filters.

There is a **Thread** in **MainActivity** and, I create some classes to make my code simple.
[MyApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuUAo.png)

There are many variables that I declared in **headingFilter** class, and I want to change the values of it continuously.  [headingFilter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i7pT.png)

My question is how can I do this.

I thought that it is possible like the picture3, but it was impossible.
  [picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nejtC.png)

I tried like the picture4, but the value which I declared in **headingFilter** class didn't change at all.  [picture4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSSKY.png)

I think that the value does not change because the thread performs **headingFilter hFilter = new headingFilter();** continuously.

Please help me ~~~

Answer (score 0):

Make the headingFilter class static to access it.

change

`public class headingFilter {`

to

`public static class headingFilter {`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is still not working.

Comment: Can you please add more code in text format? Need to see more of the `headingFilter` class and the class that is calling `headingFilter.cal_heading()`